# XMPP Stream Delegate Not Called? Swift 3

Tags: swift, swift3, xmpp, xmppframework

I am trying to connect to an XMPP server in my iOS Application. I am using the XMPPFrameworks and for some reason the XMPP Stream delegate is not being called after I try to connect to the server. I have double checked the login information using a third party XMPP application on my computer so I do not believe it is that. Am I not setting this delegate up correctly? Am I using the wrong syntax? Do I need to set this in the app delegate instead of my view controller? Any help would be much appreciated. Below is my code

```
import UIKit
import XMPPFramework
class ViewController: UIViewController, XMPPStreamDelegate {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    connect()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func connect() {
    let stream = XMPPStream()
    stream?.addDelegate(self, delegateQueue: DispatchQueue.main)
    stream?.myJID = XMPPJID.init(string: "XXXXXXXXXXX")
    stream?.hostName = "XXXXXXXXX"
    stream?.hostPort = 5222
    do {
        try stream?.connect(withTimeout: XMPPStreamTimeoutNone)
    } catch {
        print("error connecting")
    }
}

func xmppStreamDidConnect(sender: XMPPStream) {
    print("connected!")
    do {
        try sender.authenticate(withPassword: "XXXXXXXXXX")
    } catch {
        print("error registering")
    }
   }
}
```

Comment: #Tyler Pereira have you got any solution, i am also facing same problem.

Comment: @Tyler Pereira, Im also getting same issue.

Comment: No I haven't figured out a solution. I ended up coming up with my own logic to create a chat system that didn't use XMPP

Comment: @Manish and Tyler anyone did you got any solution..Me too having the same problem

Answer (score 0):

I think that your delegate method is not right. You can try with the delegate method given below:

```
@objc func xmppStreamDidConnect(_ sender: XMPPStream!) {
  //write your code here.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
do {
        try self.xmppController = XMPPController(hostName: server,
                                                 userJIDString: userJID,
                                                 password: userPassword)
        self.xmppController.xmppStream.addDelegate(self, delegateQueue: DispatchQueue.main)
        self.xmppController.connect()
    } catch {
        sender.showErrorMessage(message: "Something went wrong")
    }
```

and `XMPPController`

```
class XMPPController: NSObject {
var xmppStream: XMPPStream

let hostName: String
let userJID: XMPPJID
let hostPort: UInt16
let password: String

init(hostName: String, userJIDString: String, hostPort: UInt16 = 5222, password: String) throws {
    guard let userJID = XMPPJID(string: userJIDString) else {
        throw XMPPControllerError.wrongUserJID
    }

    self.hostName = hostName
    self.userJID = userJID
    self.hostPort = hostPort
    self.password = password

    // Stream Configuration
    self.xmppStream = XMPPStream()
    self.xmppStream.hostName = hostName
    self.xmppStream.hostPort = hostPort
    self.xmppStream.startTLSPolicy = XMPPStreamStartTLSPolicy.allowed
    self.xmppStream.myJID = userJID

    super.init()

    self.xmppStream.addDelegate(self, delegateQueue: DispatchQueue.main)
}

func connect() {
    if !self.xmppStream.isDisconnected() {
        return
    }

    try! self.xmppStream.connect(withTimeout: XMPPStreamTimeoutNone)
}}
```

it works for me. required your attention this line

```
try self.xmppController = XMPPController(hostName: server,
                                                 userJIDString: userJID,
                                                 password: userPassword)
```

Comment: I found this solution here [link](https://github.com/inaka/ios-xmpp-sample)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. In my case (as I followed some tutorial) the object was not global and the delegate became nil. That's why it was not called. You have to store the object which implements XMPPStreamDelegate globally.

Comment: @AngelFSyrus in this case the object XMPPStream is created in connect() method.Which means that it is deallocated after connect() method is performed. The author should store XMPPStream object in ViewController and in this case the object will not be deallocated.